# Filter Pandas DataFrame to show only rows that contain all strings from a list of strings

Tags: pandas, filter

If we have a DataFrame:

```
   Column1  Column2
0  Alpha    This is bananas
1  Bravo    This is not
2  Charlie  This is not bananas
3  Delta    This is not a banana
4  Echo     This is not a Banana
5  Foxtrot  This is not a banananananana
```

and we want to select only the rows that include *all* the strings from a list of strings, how would we create a function to filter this? Case insensitive.

For example, if I wanted to filter specifically for `['not', 'banana']`, I could put that list into the function and it should return the following DataFrame:

```
   Column1  Column2
0  Delta    'This is not a banana'
1  Echo     'This is not a Banana'
```

The basic requirements:

1. Column2 must include all the strings from a given list (of arbitrary length) of strings. I want to be able to search for a list of 1, 2, 3, 5, 10, however many strings I want.
2. Case insensitivity (why filtering for "banana" gives rows with "banana" and "Banana")
3. Ignores results that include extra letters. Rows with "bananas" or "banana's" or "banananananana" would not be selected when filtering for "banana".

Answer (score 1):

One approach is using sets.

casefold and split the string into a list of words - then into a set.

```
>>> df.Column2.str.casefold().str.split().map(set)
0                   {bananas, this, is}
1                       {not, this, is}
2              {not, bananas, this, is}
3            {is, this, not, banana, a}
4            {is, this, not, banana, a}
5    {is, this, banananananana, not, a}
Name: Column2, dtype: object
```

You can then check if your words are
a [subset](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issubset)

```
>>> set(words) <= df.Column2.str.lower().str.split().map(set)
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
5    False
```

This can be used to index your dataframe.

```
>>> df[ set(words) <= df.Column2.str.lower().str.split().map(set) ]
  Column1               Column2
3   Delta  This is not a banana
4    Echo  This is not a Banana
```

Instead of `set(words)` - you would just make words a set instead of a list in the first place.

Another approach is regex - you put each of your words inside a positive lookahead assertion.

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = '(?i)' + ''.join(f'(?=.*(^|\s){re.escape(word)}(\s|$))' for word in words)
>>> pattern
'(?i)(?=.*(^|\\s)not(\\s|$))(?=.*(^|\\s)banana(\\s|$))'
```

Which you can use with `pandas.Series.str.contains()`

```
>>> df[ df.Column2.str.contains(pattern) ]
  Column1               Column2
3   Delta  This is not a banana
4    Echo  This is not a Banana
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Very good answer +1